# Using Sourcetree, I am trying to push my file to github

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to push my file to github using Sourcetree, however I get the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin refs/heads/challenge2/Soma:refs/heads/challenge2/Soma 
Pushing to git@github.com:camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
ERROR: Permission to camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git denied to soma11soma.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

REPLY TO EDIT (Thank you TheGeorgeous)

I implemented

```
git remote add source http://github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
```

and

```
git push source <branch_name>
```

then I got a message;

```
Soma-Suzuki:~ Suzuki$ git remote add source http://github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
Soma-Suzuki:~ Suzuki$ git push source challenge2/Soma
Username for 'https://github.com': soma11soma
Password for 'https://soma11soma@github.com': 
Counting objects: 5322, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1569/1569), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5322/5322), 6.13 MiB | 237.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5322 (delta 2449), reused 5317 (delta 2447)
To http://github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
 * [new branch]      challenge2/Soma -> challenge2/Soma
```

And next, I tried to push, using Sourcetree.

But I got the error message;

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin refs/heads/challenge2/Soma:refs/heads/challenge2/Soma 
Pushing to http://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
remote: Permission to camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git denied to soma11soma.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Completed with errors, see above
```

Comment: Does source tree ask for your credentials when you do this operation? Also verify that you have rights for the repo.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!
They do not ask me anything.
How can I veryfy the rights?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your remote is configured using ssh and you may not have configured your ssh.

First open the Source Tree terminal

Then remove your remote like this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then add this remote:

```
git remote add origin http://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
```

They try to push again.

**EDIT**

Based on what you have told in comments, you may have to do this

```
git remote add source http://github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
git push source <branch_name>
```

**EDIT 2**

That error is because the correct remote is `source` but SourceTree tries to push to `origin` to which you have no write permissions.

Check you remotes using

```
git remote -v
```

and remove all remotes then add the correct remote as `origin`

```
git remote add origin http://github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
```

Comment: I implemented 
'Soma-Suzuki:EnergyDataSimulationChallenge Suzuki$ git remote rm origin
Soma-Suzuki:EnergyDataSimulationChallenge Suzuki$ git remote add origin http://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git'

but, I got the same error messsage:

Comment: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin refs/heads/challenge2/Soma:refs/heads/challenge2/Soma 
Pushing to http://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
remote: Permission to camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git denied to soma11soma.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Completed with errors, see above

Comment: Are you allowed to write to the repo?

Comment: From what I see in the README of the repo, you are unlikely to have write access to the repo. You are supposed to create a fork, make your changes there and open a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!
But I am very biginner..
1:How can I create a fork?
2:How can I make my changes there and 
3:How to open a pull request.

Comment: You already have a fork on your github account. You should clone that repo, make your changes and push it there. It is very easy to open a pull request
https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I successfully cloned it and made my change.
But the thing is that I cannot push it....

Comment: what is '-v –' ?


An error message is;

Soma-Suzuki:EnergyDataSimulationChallenge Suzuki$ git remote -v-
error: unknown option `'
usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]
   or: git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--tags|--no-tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>

Comment: or: git remote rename <old> <new>
   or: git remote remove <name>
   or: git remote set-head <name> (-a | --auto | -d | --delete |<branch>)
   or: git remote [-v | --verbose] show [-n] <name>
   or: git remote prune [-n | --dry-run] <name>
   or: git remote [-v | --verbose] update [-p | --prune] [(<group> | <remote>)...]
   or: git remote set-branches [--add] <name> <branch>...
   or: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
   or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>

Comment: Oh! I see!!

I got this message!

Comment: origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[soma11soma]/[EnergyDataSimulationChallenge].git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[soma11soma]/[EnergyDataSimulationChallenge].git (push)
upstream https://github.com/econchick/new-coder.git (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/econchick/new-coder.git (push)

Comment: git add remote source https://github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
Run this command

Comment: I got this message;

Soma-Suzuki:~ Suzuki$ git add remote source github.com/soma11soma/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge.git
fatal: pathspec 'remote' did not match any files

Comment: what the heck.. I could not edit my question...


"You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more."

Answer (score 1):

In SourceTree: Tools-Options-Authentication then select "Set as default" for the correct account and push worked for me.